# Create a cartesian product of k vectors in R

Tags: r, cartesian

suppose I have a vector and I want to create a cartesian product of k same vectors, How do I implement this in R.

Like, my vector is

```
m
[1] 1 2
```

and k is 3,

how do I get a result like a cartesian product of 3 m.

Comment: Probably `data.table::CJ(m,m,m)` or `expand.grid(m,m,m)`?

Comment: `m %o% m %o% m`, or more generally, `Reduce(outer, rep(list(m), 3))`

Comment: @alistaire, post as answre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cartesian product is implemented in R as `outer`, or its infix version `%o%`. Thus:

```
m %o% m %o% m

# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    4
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    4
# [2,]    4    8
```

or in a more easily expandable form,

```
Reduce(outer, rep(list(m), 3))
```

which returns the same thing.

Comment: The outer product is **not** the Cartesian product